# AWS Multi-zone IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, high-availability, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to create an IP address that can be used in multiple availability zones?

For example:
VPC: 10.0.0.0/16
Subnet1: 10.0.0.0/24
Subnet2: 10.0.1.0/24

2 Elastic Network Interfaces: ENI-1 and ENI-2 
The 'source/dest check' wil be disabled on the 2 ENI's.

If I take a virtual IP (eg 10.1.1.1/32) and modify the routing table:
route table 1 (net 10.0.0.0/24)
 10.1.1.1/32 via ENI-1
route table 2 (net 10.0.1.0/24)
 10.1.1.1/32 via ENI-2

I launch 2 instances (each in different subnets) and assign ENI-1 to the first instance. ENI-2 will be added to the second instance.

Afterwards I use for example 'heartbeat on Linux' to bring the IP 10.1.1.1 live on the first instance.

Would such a setup work? I want to create a multi-zone high available setup without using a DNS-faiover.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-zone alternative you can put both instances in the same elastic load balancer and abstract that way. Although this won't work for multi-region.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you've described is not possible since a subnet cannot exist in multiple availability zones. When you create an ENI, you choose a subnet for it, and any IP you assign to that ENI must be in the range of that subnet. ENIs in two different AZs thus could not both be assigned the same address.

Instead you can use either an ELB or service such as HAProxy to avoid DNS-based failover.